# How to store URLs in properties file and access them in templates using Spring and Thymeleaf

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to create a simple navigation bar with links to other websites/servers using Spring Boot and Thymeleaf. I want to store these URLs in my 'application.properties' and access them via th:href. When I try to access them, it is not redirecting me to this URL.

Here is the HTML:

```
<li class="dropdown-submenu">
    <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Menu</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a th:href="#{foo.bar}">Selection 1</a></li>
```

In application.properties:

```
foo.bar=http://www.example.com
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out this notation works:

```
<li class="dropdown-submenu">
<a tabindex="-1" href="#">Menu</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a th:href="@{${@environment.getProperty('foo.bar')}}>Selection 1</a></li>
```

Comment: Also `${@environment.getProperty('foo.bar')}` worked by me today.

Answer (score 0):

/#{foo.bar} should be pointing to a value in your MessageSouce which is not populated by Configurations(i.e. application.properties in Spring Boot) but instead looks at MessageSource files (i.e. messages.properties in Spring Boot). This would leave your template unchanged.

Otherwise if you have foo.bar in the Configuration and wish not to duplicate the property you can Inject foo.bar like this

//inside a controller class

```
@Value("${foo.bar}")
String myUrl;

@RequestMapping("/mine")
public ModelAndView viewWithFooBarLink() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("templateWithFooBarReference"):
    mav.put("linkRef", myUrl);
    return mav;
}
```

Your view

```
<li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Menu</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a th:href="${linkRef}">Selection 1</a></li>
```

Good reference for this information.
http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standarddialect5minutes.html